# How to unset a set query variable?

Tags: theme-development, variables, query-variable

My theme file, multiple times over, <s>passes</s> sets a variable <s>to a template part</s> used in a subsequent template part file via `set_query_var`, like so...

```
set_query_var('feature_id', array(143866));
set_query_var('tax_meta_value',  'Payments');
get_template_part('partials/page-blocks/block_tag_new');

set_query_var('tax_meta_value',  'Venture Capital');
get_template_part('partials/page-blocks/block_tag_new');
```

In the template part, the variable is plucked out, using `get_query_var`, as `$feature_id`.

The only problem is - in the second instance here, for example - the template part still retains a memory of the first `feature_id` value passed above.

When I call the template part in the second instance, how do I ensure that no `feature_id` value is resident, <s>since none is passed</s>?

Do I need to do something like set the ensuing `$feature_id`, within the template part file, as `global` and `unset` it? Or do that but in the calling file, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I call the template part in the second instance, how do I ensure
>   that no feature_id value is resident, since none is passed?

I'm afraid you misunderstood what [`set_query_var`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_query_var/) really does. It doesn't pass anything and it doesn't work only for the next `get_template_part` call.

OK, so what does it really do? From docs:

> Set query variable.

And here's its code:

```
function set_query_var( $var, $value ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set( $var, $value );
}
```

So now everything should be clear. So let's take a look at your original code:

```
set_query_var('feature_id', array(143866));  // <- sets query var called feature_id to 143866
set_query_var('tax_meta_value',  'Payments');  // <- set query var called tax_meta_value to Payments
get_template_part('partials/page-blocks/block_tag_new');

set_query_var('tax_meta_value',  'Venture Capital');  // <- sets tax_meta_value to Venture Capital 
// feature_id is still 143866, because it hasn't been changed
get_template_part('partials/page-blocks/block_tag_new');
```

If you want to unset the query var, you can set it to false/NULL:

```
set_query_var('feature_id', false);
```

Comment: I didn't quite misunderstand, though I think I did use incorrect language. Anyway, passing a "false" value to set_query_var absolutely works as the correct answer. Thank-you.